In Pulsar, is there a good way to override the publish time property for messages for testing purposes?
I have logic that reads past messages from a pulsar topic and sends them with the wait times between the sent messages matching the original timestamp differences.
For example:
MessageA sent at timestamp 150
MessageB sent at timestamp 200
The application would read all messages, A and B, then first send A, wait 50 milliseconds, and then send B.
The publishTime property does not appear to be easily overridable, making testing this functionality difficult.
I've tried doing this in Kotlin:
    @OptIn(ExperimentalTime::class)
    @Test
    fun `prepopulate finds messages only on or after start timestamp`() =
        runTest {
            // Given these sent messages
            PulsarContainerBuilder.createTopics(pulsarContainer, TOPICS)
            launch {
                testScheduler.timeSource.measureTime {
                    pulsarProducer.send("A")
                    delay(25L)
                    pulsarProducer.send("B")
                    delay(50L)
                    pulsarProducer.send("C")
                    delay(100L)
                    pulsarReader =
                        pulsarClient
                            .newReader(Schema.STRING)
                            .topic(TOPIC_A)
                            .startMessageId(MessageId.earliest)
                            .create()
                }
            }

            testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(200.milliseconds)

            // When
            val messages = callMain(currentTime - 150L)

            // We should only fetch the last 2 messages.
            assertThat(messages).hasSize(2)
        }
}

But the publishTime that is used is just the system time.
I've considered subclassing Pulsar's Message interface and overriding getPublishTime() but that gets quite hairy as it requires overriding a dozen other functions in Message, among other issues.
Is there another idea worth trying?
Note: In Kafka, one could send messages constructed from the ProducerRecord class which accepts a timestamp param in the constructor.
